# Running unit test with gradle

Tags: gradle, junit

I am pretty new to gradle.

I am trying to do a simple tutorial on junit5 and gradle (https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/testing/junit-5-tutorial-running-unit-tests-with-gradle/). Everything works fine when i do "./gradlew test". However, doing it the second time it gives me

`$ ./gradlew test
:compileJava NO-SOURCE
:processResources NO-SOURCE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:junitPlatformTest UP-TO-DATE
:test SKIPPED`

I was under the impression that ./gradlew test should run all my tests. Why is their execution being skipped?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's being skipped because you just ran the tests, didn't change anything to the inputs or the outputs of the task, and running the tests again is thus unnecessary: the result will (or at least should) be identical.

See [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:up_to_date_checks).